# Comparing two excel files that use ODBC to connect to an Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, excel, odbc, compare

I have two excel files.  Both carry out the same task but one seems to be an older version.  I have to troubleshoot the differences between them to see if there is subtle things like field length differences or sorting differences.

The obvious variance is one file automatically connects to the db. (Desired outcome) The other prompts for server name every time which is annoying to the user.  (See screenshot below)

I guess I have two questions both very closely related:

- How do I compare the files against each other?
- Where does the ODBC prompt box retrieve the populated fields from? (perhaps I can modify it to include the server-name)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwgpA.jpg

Software:

Excel 2003
Oracle 11G 11.1.0.7.0

Comment: Question is a bit confusing in my opinion - the retrieve the data you need a SQL (and that defines populated fields). The second, mostly unrelated part is the connection. I am afraid I cannot see the image in the link, but I guess there is a prompt for user/password. That information can be stored in the connection string (and it would cause automatic connection).

Comment: I'm still not sure how to view/edit the fields that automatically load into the prompt.  Can you advise?